# Errors when mocking firebase within a React app using Jest and React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test a component which calls `firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail()` on click, so I want to test that firebase is being called onClick, but am not sure how to implement - I don't want to call the api in a test.

I would love some guidance on mocking/intercepting firebase calls in general.

I am using React with Jest and React Testing Library.

This is the component in question:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'

interface PFProps {
  firebase: firebase.app.App
}

interface S {
  email: string
}

interface Error {
  message?: string
}

const PasswordForget = ({ firebase }: PFProps) => {
  const initialState = { email: '' }
  const stateReducer = (state: S, update: { [x: string]: string }) => ({
    ...state,
    ...update,
  })
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(stateReducer, initialState)
  const [error, setError] = React.useState<Error>()

  const isValid = () => validator.isEmail(state.email)

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    if (!isValid()) {
      return setError({ message: messages.emailIsInvalid })
    }

    firebase
      .auth()
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(state.email)
      .then(success => console.log(success))
      .catch(error => setError(error))
    dispatch(initialState)
  }

  const handleChange = ({
    currentTarget: { name, value },
  }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setError(undefined)
    dispatch({ [name]: value })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} data-testid="form" noValidate>
        {error && error.message && <FormErrorPanel message={error.message} />}
        <Input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          data-testid="pwf-email"
          value={state.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Enter your email address"
        />
        <Button>Reset password</Button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

const PasswordForgetLink = () => (
  <p>
    <Link to={ROUTES.PASSWORD_FORGET}>Forgotten password</Link>
  </p>
)

export { PasswordForgetLink }
export default withFirebase(PasswordForget)
```

This is how I am currently trying to mock firebase:

```
import React from 'react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import { FirebaseContext } from '../../Firebase'
import firebase from '../../Firebase'

import PasswordForget from '../index'

jest.mock('../../Firebase/firebase', () => {
  return {
    auth: jest.fn(() => ({
      sendPasswordResetEmail: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    })),
  }
})

afterEach(cleanup)

const setup = () => {
  const utils = render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={firebase}>
      <PasswordForget />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  )
  const form = utils.getByTestId('form')
  const emailInput = utils.getByTestId('pwf-email') as HTMLInputElement
  const h1 = utils.getByText(/Forgotten Password/i)
  return {
    h1,
    form,
    emailInput,
    ...utils,
  }
}

test('should call sendPasswordResetEmail method when the form is submitted with a valid email', () => {
  const { form, emailInput } = setup()
  const email = 'peterparker@foo.com'
  fireEvent.change(emailInput, { target: { value: email } })
  expect(emailInput.value).not.toBeNull()
  fireEvent.submit(form)
  expect(firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

But I am getting the error:

> Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Many thaks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using create-react-app, you can try to add a "**mocks**" folder inside the "src" folder, then add a "firebase.js" inside "**mocks**" folder

in "firebase.js":

```
const mockFirebase = {
  auth: jest.fn(() => mockFirebase ),
  sendPasswordResetEmail: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(fakeResponse))
};

export { mockFirebase as default };
```

"fakeResponse" is your expected response.

then delete these in your test.js:

```
jest.mock('../../Firebase/firebase', () => {
  return {
    auth: jest.fn(() => ({
      sendPasswordResetEmail: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    })),
  }
})
```

check the Jest official site for more info: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks