# Mocking library hook with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, jestjs

### Setup

I'm using a library called [react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/auth) in a component of mine.

```js
// Component.tsx
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Firebase } from '../firebase/firebase';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';


export const Component = () => {
  // Note that Firebase.getAuth is a static method of a class of mine for getting the firebase authentication object
  const [user, loading ] = useAuthState(Firebase.getAuth());


  if (!loading && !user) {
    // ... stuff
  }

  return (
    <div>

      ...stuff
    </div>
  );
};
```

### A way that works

I'm trying to mock out the `useAuthState` call in one of my tests and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out the optimal way to perform the mock. I've found a solution that works:

```js
// Component.test.tsx
import {useAuthState} from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'

jest.mock('react-firebase-hooks/auth', () => ({
  useAuthState: jest.fn()
}));
```

However, the above mocking implementation makes it impossible to get IDE completion for the mock objects. For example, here's me trying to set up a mock return value:

```js
      test(`component correctly loads`, () => {
         useAuthState.mockReturnValue([true, false])

        // renderApp is a utility method of mine to render using react-testing-library
        const { getByText } = renderApp();

        // expect some stuff
      });
```

### My preferred outcome (and attempt 1)

What I'm finding is that I don't get autocomplete on `useAuthState`.

Ideally how I'd like to declare the mock would be something closer to

```js
const mockAuth = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-firebase-hooks/auth', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {useAuthState: mockAuth}
  })
});
```

which would then let me alter the `mockAuth` object nicely through the tests I declare (and get autocomplete), eg:

```js
      test(`component correctly loads`, () => {
         mockAuth.mockReturnValue([true, false])

        // renderApp is a utility method of mine to render using react-testing-library which renders Component
        const { getByText } = renderApp();

        // expect some stuff
      });
```

However, with the above implementation, I get the following error: `(0 , _auth.useAuthState) is not a function or its return value is not iterable` in `Component`.

### Attempt 2

I've also tried declaring the mock as

```js
const mockAuth = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-firebase-hooks/auth', () => ({
    useAuthState: mockAuth
}));
```

but that gives me an error of `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockAuth' before initialization`.

### Attempt 3

I've also tried

```js
const mockAuth = jest.fn();
import {useAuthState} from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'
jest.mock('react-firebase-hooks/auth', () => ({
    useAuthState: mockAuth
}));
```

but that gives the same error.

### Closing question

Is there a way for me to declare a mock function "outside" of the mock declaration so that I can get autocomplete for it?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305823/errors-when-mocking-firebase-within-a-react-app-using-jest-and-react-testing-lib or create sandbox

Comment: I don't see how that helps declare the mock function outside of the declaration of the module mock.

Comment: can you make codesanbox?

Comment: @DaniilLoban [CodeSandbox doesn't support jest mocking](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/513). I had to figure that out the hard way I thought you'd like to know.

Comment: I just need minimal setup project not for run in sunbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use another file for the mock, you should be golden to change the implementation and still preserve the TypeScript Intellisense.

### `src/App.test.jsx`

```
import App from "../App";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useAuthState } from "../__mocks__/react-firebase-hooks/auth";

it("should be mocked", () => {
  // Change the implementation of the mock
  useAuthState.mockReturnValue([true, false]);
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  // Expect that the app file got the mocked value
  expect(useAuthState).toBeCalledWith("my auth");
  expect(getByText("true,false")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

### `src/__mocks__/react-firebase-hooks/auth.js`

```js
export const useAuthState = jest.fn();
```

### `src/App.js`

```
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";

export default function App() {
  const test = useAuthState("my auth");
  return <div>{test.toString()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: whoa, that's cool. I hadn't seen that syntax before. Any chance you have a link to docs I can read? Is this the preferred way to mock? What are the downsides to this approach?

Comment: The only downside I can think of is having to make a separate file. Sometimes that's ideal, sometimes it's a bit annoying. Here is related the documentation (although sparse on this specific model) https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks